# Print data in dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have the following data.

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'cls': 'ABC', 'measure': ['inter', 'batch'], 'Pend Job': [101, 93], 'Run Job': [302, 1327], 'Time': [56, 131]})

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'cls': 'DEF', 'measure': ['inter', 'batch'], 'Pend Job': [24279, 421], 'Run Job': [4935, 5452], 'Time': [75, 300]})
```

I want to print it on pandas Dataframe in attached format. Any idea how to do this ?

### Below is the Desired Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY78c.png)

Comment: as per the attached image you need multiIndexed  DataFrame outout.

Answer (score 1):

First data frame

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'cls': 'ABC', 
    'measure': ['inter', 'batch'], 
    'Pend Job': [101, 93], 
    'Run Job': [302, 1327], 
    'Time': [56, 131]
})

    cls     measure Pend Job    Run Job     Time
0   ABC     inter   101         302         56
1   ABC     batch   93          1327        131
```

Second data frame

```
test2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'cls': 'DEF', 
    'measure': ['inter', 'batch'], 
    'Pend Job': [24279, 421], 
    'Run Job': [4935, 5452], 
    'Time': [75, 300]
})

    cls     measure Pend Job    Run Job     Time
0   DEF     inter   24279       4935        75
1   DEF     batch   421         5452        300
```

and last: concatenate data frames and group by `cls` and convert series to list

```
pd.concat([test1, test2]).groupby('cls').agg(list)


        measure         Pend Job        Run Job         Time
cls                 
ABC     [inter, batch]  [101, 93]       [302, 1327]     [56, 131]
DEF     [inter, batch]  [24279, 421]    [4935, 5452]    [75, 300]
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks Slava. This is nice. Can you pls help me to print the o/p in attached format as well.

Comment: I think we can use "MultiIndex" feature but how to implement it no idea.